# Update Bios of a brandless laptop

Tags: laptop, bios

I know this might sound stupid but I bought a laptop from a chinese company 'feedme'. I just noticed now that they don't have their own website to where you normally download the needed files to update your bios.

The laptop runs only in UEFI or LEGACY. I need to install a Win7-UEFI on it but gives an error code 0x00000d.

I searched the error code online and found out its a bios problem since my windows 8 and 10 UEFI works on it and rhey suggested to update the bios.

Is there a way to safely update the bios of a brandless laptop? Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the manufacturer offers no bios update then u are out of luck.

Comment: @Moab is there a way to know the laptop's real manufacturer? I found out that feedme company are just rebranding laptops

Comment: The only true way to do this is to open it and look for any brand on the motherboard to see where it comes from. Frequently if the computer is working, BIOS does not need to be updated. Why are you needing to update it?

Comment: These are made in china for any company that wants a private branded laptop.

Comment: @John I need to install Windows 7x64-UEFI on it. I read a thread that it can be done with a bios update

Comment: windows 8 to 10 x64 UEFIs works, but gives an error when i tried it with windows 7

Comment: The first time I needed UEFI was with Windows 8 (and did that update). I never needed UEFI for Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: @John the laptop only gives UEFI and LEGACY options in its bios though. Any suggestions?

Comment: It possibly was designed to run Windows 10 and may not run Windows 7. That is reasonably common a year after Windows 7 went away. You can put Windows 10 on it and run Windows 7 as a virtual machine. That is worth considering.